# Maths Rug Question

Tags: problem-solving

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what this question is asking.

Can someone please draw a diagram and show what they are asking us to find. (btw, this question was asked before but I didn't quite understand what we are expected to find out)

Jack works in a rug shop. He has three rugs with a combined area of 200square meters.

He arranged the rugs so they overlap and cover a floor area of 140square meters.

The total floor area that is covered by exactly two layers of rugs is 24square meters.

What is the floor area that is covered by exactly three layers of rugs, in square meters.

The given answer is 18.

Please help guys!

Comment: The question is asking for the floor area that is covered by exactly three layers of rugs.   What about that is unclear?

Comment: Let a = the area of floor covered by 1 rug.  Let b= area of floor covered by 2 rugs = 24.  Let c= area covered by 3 rugs.  So a + b +c =a+24+c= 140.  That's the floor area.  a +2b + 3c = 200.   That's the rug area.  What's c?